# Get results from bigquery script

Tags: google-bigquery, dynamic-sql

I have this script running in BigQuery Cloud console :

```
DECLARE TABLE_NAME STRING;
DECLARE TOTAL FLOAT64;

SET TABLE_NAME = '`xxx.yyy.zzz`';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT("SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM ", TABLE_NAME, " WHERE 1=1 AND YEAR = 2020 AND NUM_MONTH = 7") INTO TOTAL;
SELECT TOTAL;
```

I believed this would display the results of last query but it only says that 2 instructions where treated. How do I show TOTAL variable ?

[Console snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9qCW.jpg)

Comment: This is not reproducible on my side. Going through your query history -> Open query in Editor you should be able to see two jobs in a list, one for the procedure executed and the other for the select. For each one of them you should be able to "View Results". Otherwise I would recommend to file a support case ticket: https://cloud.google.com/support

Comment: @SergiMuñoz Hello, the issue came from bad right management. A co worker with higher rights added to me a permission and then I was able to see request results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE TABLE_NAME STRING DEFAULT '`project.dataset.table`';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) TOTAL FROM ' || TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE 1=1 AND YEAR = 2020 AND NUM_MONTH = 7';
```

Snapshot:
[image]

Comment: Please let me know if it is helpful !

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: I have added the snapshot ! Let me know if you expect a different outcome !

Comment: Thanks for the snapshot, I don't have the same console !

Comment: Not sure about that: `https://console.cloud.google.com/`